# add a new bit to the left of byte and discard right bit of byte

Tags: bit, shift

every one!
if there is a new bit to insert one byte, how can I solve with it?
for example:

if there comes a new bit 1 to a byte(ex.0xaa) 
10101010==>11010101

if there comes a new bit 0 t0 a byte(ex.0xaa) 
10101010==>01010101

any suggestion to do it?

Comment: What programming language? Typically you'd solve this with [bit shifting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operators#Bit_shifts), but you've provided no context.

Comment: i can't understand your problem rewrite, i guess english isn't your first language (same here)

Comment: What language?  Cobol?  Fortran? C? C#? C++? Pascal? VB? Assembly? Klingon?

Comment: is the new bit the low order bit or high order bit?

Comment: The programing language is C, the new bit is the highest bit.

Answer (score 1):

if there is a bit

```
0x80 | (0xaa>>1)
```

if htere is no bit

```
0x7F & (0xaa>>1)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's an odd request, but it can be done.  This code takes two parameters: First the original Byte in the form of an integer, and second the bit you want add to the left after the bit shift in the form of a 0 or a 1.  Shifting to the right is easy with integers; just divide by 2 and the remainder gets dropped.  Let’s take 2 to the power of 7 and store it in the @FlagNumber variable to use in our calculations.

If we want to set the bit on the left to zero, we need to check the value first.  The bit in the eight place should already be zero, but let’s check just in case someone passed a value greater than 255 let’s check.  If for some reason it is set to 1, we will use a simple ^ (xor) to toggle it off.

If we want to set the bit on the left to one, we will use a simple | (or) to turn in on)

I'll wrap it all up in a function, and here is what you get.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Jacob Raines
-- Create date: 2013-04-03
-- Description: Shift byte to the right and set 8th bit
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Flag_ByteAppendLeft
(
    @InputByte int,     --10101010
    @InputBit int       --0 or 1
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    /* Examples & Notes 
        SELECT dbo.Flag_ByteAppendLeft(170, 1)  --(10101010, 1) Should Return 11010101 (213)
        SELECT dbo.Flag_ByteAppendLeft(170, 0)  --(10101010, 0) Should Return 01010101 ( 85)
    */
    DECLARE @OutputByte int
    DECLARE @FlagPower as int
    DECLARE @FlagNumber as int

    SET @OutputByte = @InputByte / 2 --Bit Shift once to the right
    SET @FlagNumber = 7 --Flag 7 (starting at 0) is the 8th bit.
    SET @FlagPower = POWER(2, @FlagNumber)  

    IF (@InputBit = 0)
    BEGIN
        IF (@OutputByte & @FlagPower = @FlagPower)  -- If set
        BEGIN
            SET @OutputByte = @OutputByte ^ @FlagPower  -- Then Toggle Flag with xor
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @OutputByte = @OutputByte | @FlagPower      -- Set Flag
    END

    RETURN @OutputByte
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, you can do the following if it's an `unsigned int`.

Adding a `logic 1` bit to the left.

```
x = 0x80000000 | (x >> 1);
```

Adding a `logic 0` bit to the left.

```
x = x >> 1;
```

Noting that in C , `>>` is a [logical shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift) due to the `unsigned int` and therefore places a `logic 0` bit to the left when shifting right.

And also note that `0x8000000` will only work because of the extra bit in an `unsigned int`.