# How to insert a new Bit at MSB and ignoring all other bits

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, bitwise-and, bitwise-or

I found this: [add a new bit to the left of byte and discard right bit of byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494765/add-a-new-bit-to-the-left-of-byte-and-discard-right-bit-of-byte)
but:

```
x = 0x80000000 | (x >> 1);
```

doesn't seam what I'm looking for.

```
union {
  unsigned char byte_variable;
  // a structure with 8 single bit bit-field objects, overlapping the union member "byte"
  struct {
                unsigned b0: 1;
                unsigned b1: 1;
                unsigned b2: 1;
                unsigned b3: 1;
                unsigned b4: 1;
                unsigned b5: 1;
                unsigned b6: 1;
                unsigned b7: 1;
  };
} byte_8;
```

apparently setting a bit like this:

```
byte_8.b7 = 1;
```

doesn't work if you use a Union.

How to add a new bit at the MSB and disregarding or without altering all other bits in the variable.

```
byte_8.byte_variable;
```

Comment: what is msb for you? is it most left bit or is it most left significant 0?

Comment: @IłyaBursov  MSB =  most significant bit, the upper most bit or bit 7 in a byte, just like the union.

Comment: `byte_variable |= (1 << 7);`

Comment: @IłyaBursov darn, almost good accept i choose the &.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ordering of bitfields within a union is implementation defined, so what you tried isn't guaranteed to work.

If you want to set the highest order bit in an `unsigned char`, just OR the variable with a value that has only that bit set:

```
unsigned char x;
// set x
x = x | 0x80;
```

Comment: thnx, i forgot that 0x80 = 0b10000000

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more general approach to set the msb you can do it as:

```
int setMSB(int x, int b){
    return b ? x | (1 << sizeof(x)*8-1) : x & ~(1 << sizeof(x)*8-1);
}
```

where x is the number (you can modify the x data type as you wish) and b is the bit to put. Note that it could be safe to check if b is either 0 or 1 (or better use boolean).

If you set b=1 the variable becomes x | 100... in this way you set the msb keeping the other bits consistent (as other users have suggested already).

Otherwise if you set b=0 the variable becomes x & 011... the msb will be 0 while the others bit don't change their value